# Array of BigIntegers is saved as string in Spring + Mongo

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

When I try to save an object that has an array of BigInteger, I discovered that Spring Data Mongo saves the values as strings instead of ObjectIds.

The object was originally stored in Mongo with an array of ObjectIds, but when saving that gets converted to strings.

I assumed the problem is with the fact that this is an array or list, and not a BigInteger directly. Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you add a bit of sample code? What do the domain classes look like? How do you interact with the store?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on my own. It appears that my BigInteger[] should be changed to a ObjectId[] but without the @OneToMany annotation on it.

The @OneToMany annotation caused the forced conversion to String.

A better solution would be to use a custom annotation like @ObjectId, in the same spirit as @DBRef, but this is not included in Spring Data Mongo, and I don't have the skill yet to set this up.

If anyone feels interested to help out, I'd be more than happy and select a different best answer.

Comment: That doesn't make too much sense, actually? Which @OneToMany annotation are you referring to?

Comment: The field in my original code was a BigInteger[] with annotation @OnyToMany on it. I did not pay much attention to the annotation. After I dropped it and started using ObjectId[], my problem was solved.